# How to send SMS with Delphi XE5 in Android

Tags: android, delphi, sms, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Does anybody know how to get this to work?
The closest I got was the code below, but got no success.
At first, it gives you some hope when it tells you need the `SEND_SMS` permission. But after you setup this permission, nothing happens!

```
uses
 Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  smsManager: JSmsManager;
  smsTo, smsFrom: JString;
begin
  smsManager:= TJSmsManager.JavaClass.getDefault;
  smsTo:= StringToJString('552199999999'); //replace with the right destination number
  smsFrom:= StringToJString('552499999999'); //replace with the right originator number
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsTo, smsFrom, StringToJString(Edit1.Text), nil, nil);
end;
```

Comment: Can you send a message to the same number from that phone manually? Does adding a country prefix number help? For example, country prefix number for my country is +381.

Answer (score 13):

Try to pass empty value (`nil`) to the `scAddress` parameter of the [`sendTextMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) function call to use the current default SMS center:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.Telephony;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  smsTo: JString;
  smsManager: JSmsManager;
begin
  smsManager := TJSmsManager.JavaClass.getDefault;
  smsTo := StringToJString('091...');
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsTo, nil, StringToJString('Test SMS'), nil, nil);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to **sendTextMessage** is not the "sender" number, rather it identifies the SMS provider *service center*.

You almost certainly did not want to specify anything here.  Simply pass **nil** and the **SMSManager** will use the device default service center for delivering your message.

```
sRecipient := StringToJString(edRecipient.Text);
sMessage   := StringToJString(edMessage.Text);
sendTextMessage(sRecipient, nil, sMessage, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 1):

See also:

http://delphi-android.blogspot.dk/2013/10/how-to-send-sms-with-delphi-on-android.html

for a copy & paste function.

I like to have such functions in a separate unit, instead of putting it into the Button's event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with JIntend object as below

```
procedure CreateSms(const Number, Msg: string);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  Uri: Jnet_Uri;
begin
  Uri := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(Format('smsto:%s', [Number])));
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW, Uri);
  Intent.putExtra(StringToJString('sms_body'), StringToJString(Msg));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

Comment: `Format 'smsto:%s' is invalid or incompatible with argument.`

Comment: I have change technology a over year ago after just few months in Delphi and I can not help you now :/

Comment: There's no problem, I appreciate your concern. However, this seems not to be working anymore.